# quantum mechanics probability of +1 spin between arbitrary directions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

So there are two unit vectors $\hat{m}$ and $\hat{n}$ with arbitrary directions in 3D space.

There is a spin operator along a particular direction in space, say that of $\hat{r}$, is:

$\sigma_r= \begin{bmatrix}
r_z & r_x-ir_y \\
r_x+ir_y & -r_z
\end{bmatrix}$

..which has the eigenvalues +1,-1.

Here is the question:

Suppose that a spin is prepared so that $\sigma_m = +1$. The apparatus is then rotated to the $\hat{n}$ direction and $\sigma_n$ is measured. What is the probability that the result is $+1$?

Now I've tried this using spherical coordinates, and Cartesian coordinates but it always ends up in a huge spaghetti of algebra. I have a feeling I'm doing something subtly wrong or missing some fundamental facts.

Here is what my procedure of attempt was:

I find the eigenvector (the possible state) of $\sigma_m$ corresponding to the eigenvalue +1.
I get the normalized vector:

$|m_+>  \ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1-m_z)}} \begin{bmatrix}
m_x-im_y \\
1-m_z
\end{bmatrix}$

Similarly, I find the same for the $\sigma_n$ operator:

$|n_+> \ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1-n_z)}} \begin{bmatrix}
n_x-in_y \\
1-n_z
\end{bmatrix}$

Then, for the probability I simply find (or try to..) $P = |<n_+|m_+>|^2$.
The answer given is $\cos^2(\rho/2)$ where $cos(\rho)=\hat{n}.\hat{m}$.

Am I attempting this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce the "spaghetti of algebra" you can reorient the
coordinates. If $\hat{z}'=\hat{m}$ then in spherical coordinates you have
$$
\sigma_\hat{m}= 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
 \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
 \sin(\theta)  & -\cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where $\cos(\theta)=\hat{n} \cdot \hat{m}$. It's easier to find the eigenvectors
of this matrix using: 
$$
\sin(\theta/2)=
\sin(\theta-\theta/2)=
\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta/2)-\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta/2)
$$
and the analogous equation for cosine.

Therefore
$$
|n_{+}> = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\cos(\theta/2) \\
\sin(\theta/2) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and finally:
$$
|<m_+|n_+>|^2=\cos^2(\theta/2)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Effectively, that is re-orienting our 3D coordinates such that m and n lie in the same plane formed by a pair of new axis - am I right? Also, what does the z' mean?

Comment: You're right, that way you have less variables. z' mean the z axis of the new coordinate system that way there is no azimuthal angle in the equations.